# Post List of list of string from Javascript to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

This is my JSON data that I am trying to POST:

```
{
  "UploadText": [       
    [
      "Stamp Duty+Rgst",
      "Extra on actuals (approximately @ 5.9%)",
      "4.90%",
      "",
      "688,225",
      "",
      "",
      "688,225"
    ],
    [
      "share certificate",
      "250",
      "",
      "",
      "250",
      "",
      "",
      "250"
    ],
    [
      "Legal charges",
      "Lumpsum (Approx 10 - 20k)",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "18,000",
      "18,000"
    ],
    [
      "TOTAL",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "16,122,863",
      "",
      "5,564,372",
      "21,687,235"
    ]
  ]
}
```

and this is my controller method:

```
public void UploadText(UploadItem uploadItem)
        {

        }
```

and this is the actual class:

```
 public class UploadItem
    {
        public List<string[]> UploadText { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to POST the data using Angular and the request is correct sent. But the model binding is not properly happening. My `UploadText` inside the `UploadItem` is always NULL. If I change to `List<List<string>>` it is still NULL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OK, found. I forgot to put [FromBody]. It appears this is the cool new keyword in API. WIthout that the model binding doesn't appear to work. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

in your JSON change:

```
"UploadText":
```

to

```
"uploadItem":
```

as this is expected parameter, looking at the below:

```
public void UploadText(UploadItem uploadItem)
```

Comment: But the item inside uploadItem is called uploadText. That is why I used uploadText

Comment: yes, but your function is expecting a parameter named: uploadItem of type UploadItem.
you can change UploadText(UploadItem uploadItem) to UploadText(UploadItem UploadText)

Comment: I changed it but there is no effect as expected.

Comment: Please see my commment.